# Azure File Storage / File Share - Port 445 - Why

Tags: azure, storage, smb

This is a "why" question, not a "how" question....

SMB is known to have issues with security (MAJOR ones). Azure has multiple ways to avoid using 445 over the open internet....

This leads to a repeated question of WHY is that method shown on the connect page with high visibility (hey just copy/paste this)...

"Does Microsoft NOT understand the importance of Security? Where else may common actions with Azure be Promoted that are High Risk?

Hopefully someone from the Azure Team can provide a link to something "official" (i.e. posted on a sub-site of Microsoft.com) to be able to refer these customers to...

ps: At least three companies have decided to go elsewhere because of this (again, not the actual problem, but the inability to understand WHY Microsoft has taken such an approach).

Comment: `SMB is known to have issues with security (MAJOR ones)` not really. Unless you refer to 20 years earlier or re-enabled obsolete SMBv1 just to be able to connect to a Linux file server with a misconfigured Samba server **and** disabled any encryption and security. features.

Comment: At best, this isn't a programming question. You may want to post a question at https://serverfault.com and ask why SMB is *not* a security problem, or find people that can help you secure your network.

Comment: `At least three companies have decided to go` and dozens if not hundreds of thousands of other companies haven't. Especially the Fortune 500 companies that are constantly under attack by hackers and so know how to secure their networks.

Comment: BTW **everyone uses a VPN**. And **Windows uses VPNs** for branch office connectivity, since the 2000s. Azure, AWS and Google also offer VPNs. If you don't use a VPN to connect to the cloud, you're making a very explicit decision to transfer your data unencrypted. After that, it really doesn't matter what protocol you use does it?

Comment: If you [read the docs, specifically the "Encryption in Transit"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-files-networking-overview#encryption-in-transit) section you'll see that `By default, all Azure storage accounts have encryption in transit enabled.` and `Azure Files will only allow the connection if it is made with SMB 3.0+ with encryption or HTTPS`. You have to **explicitly disable encryption**. Don't do that.

Comment: Luckily, even if you do that, the data. *won't* get out of the Azure region. `an SMB 2.1 client outside of the Azure region of the Azure file share, such as on-premises or in a different Azure region, will not be able to access the file share.` Disabling encryption will only help to allow a legacy application or OS on an Azure VM to connect to that share

Comment: Once again, I *know* all of the issues with SMB. I am asking specifically about the organization of the page on the Azure Portal and why Microsoft decided to put that piece of PowerShell right on the fron page, instead of highlighting  VPN and other approaches that does not use SMB.

Alas my connections within Microsoft have disipated, and Azure has changed much since I left Microsoft 15 years ago - so I do not have a direct contact on the appropriate Microsoft Team. Since Microsoft has decided that SO is the targeted venue for no-cost support, I posted here hoping the team could say WHY....

Comment: I already posted links to the docs that show what you claim simply isn't true

Comment: As per the security issues, many carriers (such as XFinity) have totally blocked 445. There is no known policy to get them to unblock it (if anyone has contacts/approaches, that would be good). I would consider firewall issues to be security related.

Comment: Again, what you claim contradicts the docs that *clearly* explain that no unencrypted connections are allowed.

Comment: If you want to know why, the Reconnect chat is a safer place to ask. Susan may be able to get you in contact with the proper people provided your question doesn't sound like Joe Celko in the 2000s. Make sure what you claim is true though. Extraordinary claims require extraordinary evidence, and this question has none. That proof should be in the form of a Wireshark capture

Comment: If anything, it looks like the real question could be [how to access an Azure File Share](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-files-networking-overview#accessing-your-azure-file-shares) when 445 is blocked, and that's covered. int the docs in [Accessing your Azure File shares](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-files-networking-overview#accessing-your-azure-file-shares). SMB v3 is safe. If the provider or company policy blocks it, you need to use a VPN or NFS. And no matter what, remove older SMB versions

Comment: 1) Thanks for the recommendation to use Reconnect - makes perfect sense, and embarrased I did not think of it.

2) The "no unencrypted allowed" is meaningless from a usability standpoint when sme of the nations larest ISP have put hard blocks on 445...

3) On the last one - once again, I know that information is available, and that links are available... My *SOLE* question on on why the page was written the way it was, and some Microsoft produced artifact that could be linked to to explain why they put things where they did, when it allows for a person to easily get the wrong impression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving discussion to Microsoft Reconnect, because this has become cluttered with comments about SMB and VPN rather than *just* why a page was layed out the way it was, with an explanation existing as publicly referenceable Microsoft documentation on the design of the page (e.g. we put paragraph #2 before paragraph #3 because....")